# mvc jquery won't find option in select element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

So I have a view in which I create an IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) and then use this list to populate options in a Select, like so:

```
@ModelType MyModel
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Edit"

    Dim TypeList As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = {
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "American", .Text = "American"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Chinese", .Text = "Chinese"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Mexican", .Text = "Mexican"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Italian", .Text = "Italian"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Japanese", .Text = "Japanese"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Sandwich", .Text = "Sandwich"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "BBQ", .Text = "BBQ"},
    New SelectListItem() With {.Value = "Other", .Text = "Other"}
}
End Code

<h2>Edit MyModel</h2>

@Using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyModel", FormMethod.Post, New With {.name = "frmEditMyModel", .id = "frmEditMyModel"}))
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @<div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div class="text-danger">@(ViewData("mmError"))</div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.ID)

......
        <div class="form-group" id="typecombo">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Type, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control">
                    @For Each item In TypeList
                        @<option>@item.Text</option>
                    Next
                </select>
                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Type, New With {.id = "type"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Type, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="typebox">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Type, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
            </div>
        </div>
.......

    </div>  End Using
```

So being that this is an Edit page for something that already exists, I want the select element to have the option selected that equals MyModel.Type.  And on top of that, if type is "Other", show the text box in which the user can type what it is.  So here is the jquery I have:

```
@Section Scripts 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $(function () {

        // First see if the current 'type' is in the dropdown options or not
        var exists = false;
        var curType = "@Model.Type";
        $('#typecombo option').each(function () {
            if (this.Text == curType) {
                exists = true;
                $("#typecombo select").val(curType).change();
            }
        });
        if (exists == false) {
            $("#typecombo select").val("Other").change();
        }

        // Toggle show / hide of Type textbox if selection in Type combo is 'Other'
        var selection = $('#typecombo :selected').text();
        selection.trim();
        if (selection === 'Other') {
            $('#typebox').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#typebox').hide();
        }
        $('#typecombo').change(function () {
            var selection = $('#typecombo :selected').text();
            selection.trim();
            if (selection === 'Other') {
                $('#typebox').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#typebox').hide();
            }
        })
</script>
End Section
```

For whatever reason, it is not finding the value as already existing.  I tried putting an alert that displays @Model.Type when the page opens - that shows correctly.  But it doesn't matter - every time, it ends up setting the selected value to "Other" and showing the text box because it's not finding it as an option in the Select.  Why??

Comment: Just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Type, TypeList)` and delete the `@Html.HiddenFor()` and `@Html.EditorFor()` for `Type` - none of your scripts are necessary to select the correct option. And if you want the textbox to add another value, bind it to a different property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to change this section

```
        if (this.Text == curType) {
            exists = true;
            $("#typecombo select").val(curType).change();
        }
```

to

```
        if (this.text == curType) {
            exists = true;
            $("#typecombo select").val(curType).change();
        }
```

Javascript is case sensitivity. Notice this. And DOM element attribute has name `text`

Comment: @charlietfl jQuery works with DOM elements, not with model